# How to link a .so file to a managed DLL with mono

Tags: c#, mono, native, dllimport, managed-c++

I'm writing a program for embedded linux on an ARM processor in .net that uses mono to execute.  I have found that I can simply compile to either x86 or x64 architecture on my PC, copy the Debug directory over to linux, and run the program using mono myProgram.exe.  The program is working perfectly like this and mono seems to take care of the architecture mismatch.  This was true until today when I tried to incorporate an external native DLL.

I have both an x86 and x64 bit architecture of the external DLL and both work on the desktop environment fine.  I have a shim class that uses [DllImport] to load the extern functions.  However, when I try this on embedded linux with Mono I am getting a BadImageFormat exception.  My guess is that Mono somehow transitions the compiled DLLs in the exe at start up but doesn't do the same for the external.

Some other info:
1. I don't have source for the native external library.  I have x86, x64, and a .so library.
2. I have tried making a manage C++ shim that accesses the .so but can't get it to compile on the desktop since windows doesn't recognize the .so file.

Some thoughts:
1. Is there a way to embed the native DLL into a managed so that Mono will transition the native DLL too?
2. Can I link the .so file to a managed C++ project?
3. Is there a way to tell Mono to incorporate that Dll during execution?

Ultimately I'm looking for a solution that is wrapped in the exe that allows me to simply run it like I did before and control the native system.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't think that this is going to work. You've got an unmanaged C++ DLL that was compiled for x86/x64 Windows, and you're trying to run it on ARM Linux. This total mismatch is the most likely reason for the ``BadImageFormatException``.

Comment: Can you define what a "C# Native DLL" is? Are you talking about an unmanaged/native DLL or a .NET assembly written in C#? .NET DLL's are managed (not-native) and are run through a JIT compiler at runtime which is why they are (mostly) architecture agnostic. Native DLL's don't have that luxury.

Comment: @Ciaran_McCarthy In general I would agree with you, but the odd part is that I have x86 and x64 compiled DLLs copied to the Arm that run just fine using Mono.

Comment: @RonBeyer That was a typo.  Sorry it is a managed C++ DLL.

Comment: Is the DLL you are importing via `DllImport` managed or unmanaged (you mention .so files, so I guess unmanaged)? Not everything with .NET is platform agnostic, especially if you are loading an external native library that may rely on specific platform API's (like win32 or winmm).

Comment: I believe it is unmanaged as I need to use extern calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the .dll and .so files for Windows and Linux, you can probably use dll maps feature of Mono. (https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/) which are used to map Windows dll names to Linux so names.

.Net does not recognize this, but Mono does.